# require history.js plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, history.js

This is my first attempt at Require.js and I'm trying to figure out how to use jQuery plugins with it, particularly [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/) that should manage my SPA. Code below is located in main.js and the script runs but I can't figure how to actually use History.pushState(), State.getState() and other plugin methods. I keep getting `"getState is not a function"` error messages in the console.

```
(function() {
    requirejs.config(
    {
        baseUrl: 'js',
        paths: {
            'jquery': 'vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min',
            'history': 'history.js'
        },
        shim: {
            'history': {
                deps: ["jquery"],
                exports: 'History'
            }
        },
        map: {
          '*': { 'jquery': 'jquery-private' },
          'jquery-private': { 'jquery': 'jquery' }
        }
    }
   );   

   define(["jquery"], function($) {
        $(function() {

            require(['history'], function( History ){
                var 
                History = window.History,
                State = History.getState();
            });

        });
    });

})();
```

jquery-private contains this code:

```
define(['jquery'], function (jq) {
    return jq.noConflict( true );
});
```

That's everything I've got so far as I'm only trying to figure stuff out and set up a document. I'm having some doubts about `exports: History` and function param in `require(['history])` but it might be something else completely.

By the way, I've used history in a previous project so I feel like I understand how to use it, in case you might be wondering. :)

EDIT: I'm using compressed/ uncompressed versions of [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/blob/master/scripts/uncompressed/history.js) file. Adding a path didn't change a thing. With or without it I can see the script loaded in browser when required. I still get History.getState() is not a function error.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm surprised you don't have a `paths` setting for `history`. Which of the multiple files they distribute are you loading? When I look [here](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/tree/master/scripts) I see a whole bunch of subdirectories with a hole bunch of files. Also, if you inspect `window.History` just before you cal `History.getState()` what do you get?

Comment: I'm using (un)compressed history.js file. I edited the original post with the information. I get a History function if I inspect it before calling History.getState(). [link](https://i.imgsafe.org/3f009d92d4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you are accessing history in code but path is not defined

```
           require(['history'], function( History ){
```

you need to add path of history js file like jquery.

```
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min',
        'history' : '<path to js file>' 
    },
```

Try adding history along with jquery as dependency

```
define(["jquery","history"], function($,History) {

    var 
    History = window.History,
    State = History.getState();

})();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it seems it doesn't matter as I can see through the web inspector the file has loaded in browser. Still getting History.getState() is not a function error. :/ I edited the original post with the option regardless.